# uislider: knob as background, bar as foreground - like a sidewindow from a car?

Tags: iphone, uislider

if i want to have a custom slider, that looks quiet like a side-window from a car in its behaviour.

so it has a graphical mask overlying. in the background the "window" may be dragged, so that the "glass" fills the whole mask - or in the other direction that the "glass" is not there anymore.

is it possible as a modified slider or do i have to make a whole new element ?

Answer (score 0):

use UISlider property minimumvalueimage  And maximumvalueimage.
you add your glass image as minimumvalueimage and transparent image as maximumvalueimage this gives effect like slider window

Comment: how i understood, the knob has a fixed height, so i cant use a wide image.
the "glas" is a curve, like in a car, and id like to tip everywhere to make this relative movement to a slider-value